# The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% … %>)

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, master-pages, favicon

Q:

I want to add `favicon.ico` to my web application .so i add the icon to my solution then, i write the following:

## Login page :

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/favicon.ico")%>"/>
```

every thing is okay.

## Master page of the other pages:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/favicon.ico")%>"/>
```

shows the following error :

> The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control
>   contains code blocks (i.e. <% … %>).

If i use `<%#` instead and :

```
protected override void OnLoad (EventArgs e)
{
  base.OnLoad (e);
  Page.Header.DataBind ();
}
```

Is this less performance ?and how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to use any form of databinding, simply put runat="server" and the runtime will pares the tag as a GenericHtmlControl and the Url attribute will be resolved in the same manner as a normal ASP.Net ServerControl.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" runat="server" href="~/favicon.ico" />

// will render as
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```